# How to add separators between words?

Tags: java, bluej

I am writing a hangman program for my assignment and I ran into a small problem.
In my program, to separate the words, I am using '|' symbol.
Eg This is the word to be guessed:

```
U N I T E D | S T A T E S | O F | A M E R I C A
```

I have a StringBuffer variable which displays the no. of dashes
Here,

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

I tried to use the following code to insert the separator '|'

```
if(guessword.indexOf('|') == -1)
    System.out.print(" ");
else
    guessit.setCharAt(guessword.indexOf('|'),'|');
```

I know its wrong and it inserts only 1 separator.
Could you please help me in inserting the separators at the correct positions?
Also could you try to remove System.out.print(" "); as it unnecessarily leaves space.
Could I use break; instead
For the above Eg I get the display as

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ | _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

I actually want

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ | _ _ _ _ _ _ | _ _ | _ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

My main method is as follows

```
public static void main()throws IOException
{
    Hangman obj = new Hangman();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(System.out,true);

    p.println("Lets play HANGMAN");
    p.println();
    p.println("Enter your choice according to the following options.\n
               NOTE: Words are related to the topics given below.\n
               1. Sports\n2. Movies\n3. Computer\n4. Food\n5. Countries");
    p.println();
    int choice = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    obj.clearScreen();
    String bothwordandclue[] = new String[2];

    if(choice == 1)
        bothwordandclue = obj.Sports();
    else if(choice == 2)
        bothwordandclue = obj.Movies();
    else if(choice == 3)
        bothwordandclue = obj.Computers();
    else if(choice == 4)
        bothwordandclue = obj.Food();
    else if(choice == 5)
        bothwordandclue = obj.Countries();
    else
        p.println("Wrong choice");

    int counter = 6;
    String guessword = bothwordandclue[0];
    String wordclue = bothwordandclue[1];

    int lengthofword = (int)(Math.round(((double)guessword.length()/2)));
    int checkguess = 0;
    String a;
    StringBuffer guessit = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 0;i < lengthofword; i++)
        guessit = guessit.append("_ ");

    guessit.delete((2 * lengthofword)-1,(2 * lengthofword));

    if(guessword.indexOf('|') == -1)
        System.out.print(" ");
    else
        guessit.setCharAt(guessword.indexOf('|'),'|');

    p.println(guessit);
    do
    {
        p.println();
        p.println("Enter your guess letter in capitals");
        String guessletter = br.readLine();
        obj.clearScreen();

        for(int i = 0;i<lengthofword;i++)
        {
            if(guessletter.charAt(0) == guessword.charAt(2*i))
            {
                guessit.setCharAt(2*i,guessletter.charAt(0));
                checkguess=1;
            }                
        }
        if(checkguess == 1)
        {
            p.println("Correct Guess");
            p.println(guessit);
        }
        else
        {
            counter--;
            p.println("Wrong guess. You have " + counter + 
                                    " incorrect guesses left");
            p.println(guessit);
        }
        checkguess = 0;
        a = guessit.toString();
        if(a.equals(guessword))
        {
            p.println("You guessed the word!!!!!");
            counter=0;
        }        
    }while(counter>0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `indexOf` only. Just you need to use another version of that method, that takes the position from where to start searching. See [`String#indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) that you need here.

```
int index = guessword.indexOf("|");
while(index >= 0) {
   guessIt.setCharAt(index, '|')

   // Start searching for next "|" after this index
   index = guessword.indexOf("|", index+1));  
}
```

Comment: Upvote because it solves the problem more efficiently than mine, but not as obvious for a beginner. Perhaps include a link to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String, int)

Comment: Thank you so much. This cleared the problem very effectively.

Comment: @user1772079. You're welcome:). You need to mark this answer as accepted, by clicking the arrow besides the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `setCharAt` and `indexOf` only apply to one index each, which is why it is only replacing the first |. You will have to iterate through `guessword` multiple times. You can either use some of Java's other built-in String functions or use a simple for loop, i.e.

```
for(int i = 0; i < guessword.length(); i++){
    if(guessword.charAt(i) == '|')
        guessit.setCharAt(i, '|');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the post. I had already tried this before posting the question and it did not even put one separator between the words :D

Answer (score 0):

See [String.replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

And if you don't know about regex:

[Regular expression on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

[Regular expression cheat sheet](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx)

Comment: More efficient, but I don't like the idea of telling a beginner to learn regular expressions.

Comment: None of them is needed here. And why do you think Regex would work? We are replacing the characters in string based on other string

Comment: @PWhite If it's for an assigment, I suppose he will learn about regex someday, so why not today?

Comment: @Rohit Jain I didn't anwser for his precise use case, but do a suggestion of learning that will simplify his algorithm and maybe gives him a better score ;)

Comment: Thank you for your post. I have a long way to learn all these complicated stuff. I just started Java about a year ago at school and have no idea about all this but I'll definitely learn